# Java: looking for the fastest way to check String for presence of Unicode chars in certain range

Tags: java, string, unicode

I need to implement a very crude language identification algorithm. In my world, there are only two languages: English and not-English. I have ArrayList and I need to determine if each String is likely in English or the other language which has its Unicode chars in a certain range. So what I want to do is to check each String against this range using some type of "presence" test. If it passes the test, I say the String is not English, otherwise it's English. I want to try two type of tests:

1. TEST-ANY: If any char in the string falls within the range, the string passes the test
2. TEST-ALL: If all chars in the string fall within the range, the string passes the test

Since the array might be very long, I need to implement this very efficiently. What would be the fastest way of doing this in Java?

Thx

UPDATE: I am specifically checking for non-English by looking at a specific range of Unicodes rather then checking for whether the characters are ASCII, in part to take care of the "resume" problem mentioned below. What I am trying to figure out is whether Java provides any classes/methods that essentially implement TEST-ANY or TEST-ALL (or another similar test) as efficiently as possible. In other words, I am trying to avoid reinventing the wheel especially if the wheel invented before me is better anyway.

Comment: If the string is all Latin letters, it could still be non-English.

Comment: Also note, that some words (such as 'résumé'), made it into English with non-ASCII accents.

Comment: There are no secret ninja tricks to achieving this.  You will need to iterate over every character in your array and check whether or not it is in the given range of unicode chars.  Imagine the simplest code possible that performs this check, then implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I ended up implementing TEST-ANY:

```
// TEST-ANY
String str = "wordToTest";
int UrangeLow = 1234; // can get range from e.g. http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl
int UrangeHigh = 2345;
for(int iLetter = 0; iLetter < str.length() ; iLetter++) {
   int cp = str.codePointAt(iLetter);
   if (cp >= UrangeLow && cp <= UrangeHigh) {
      // word is NOT English
      return;
   } 
}
// word is English
return;
```

Answer (score 4):

I really don't think that this solution is ideal for determining language, but if you want to check to see if a string is all ascii, you could do something like this:

```
public static boolean isASCII(String s){
    boolean ret = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i)>=128){
            ret = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

So then if you try this:

```
boolean r = isASCII("Hello");
```

`r` would equal true. But if you try:

```
boolean r = isASCII("Grüß dich");
```

then `r` would equal false. I haven't tested performance, but this would work reasonably fast, because all it does is compare a character to the number 128.

But as @AlexanderPogrebnyak mentioned in the comments above, this will return false if you give it "résumé". Be aware of that.

#### Update:

> I am specifically checking for non-English by looking at a specific range of Unicodes rather then checking for whether the characters are ASCII

But ASCII *is* a range in Unicode (well at least in UTF-8). Unicode is just an extension of ASCII. What the code @mP. and I provided does is it checks to see whether each character is in a certain range. I chose that range to be ASCII, which is any Unicode character that has a decimal value of less than 128. You can just as well choose any other range. But the reason I chose ASCII is because it's the one with the Latin alphabet, the Arabic numbers, and some other common characters that would normally be in an 'English' string.

Comment: your code is costly simply because toCharArray makes a copy of the entire array. It would be best to fetch char by char, just in case the first  is non ascii which would make the entire copy a waste. i know looping over an array is faster than charAt but still.

Comment: Your code is also wrong why return Boolean, replace that with boolean.

Comment: @mP. It's always good to have someone review your code. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Hassan As I stated in my update, the goal was to be able to check any Unicode range, i.e. for this to work not just for ASCII but more generally. And as I stated in the original post, I have to check for non-English and declare English if a string does nit pass the test rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isAscii( String s ){
    int length = s.length;
    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++){
       final char c = s.charAt( i );
       if( c > 'z' ){
          return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

@Hassan thanks for picking the typo replaced test against big Z with little z.

Comment: I would change 'Z' to something else, as the entire lowercase alphabet and some other characters come after 'Z'.